# R: How to check if there is a index date column?

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

I'm writing an export function for xts and data frames. And the data to export needs to have always the same structure: Date column and then 1 up to n data columns. This works quite good already, if I convert everything to a data frame before exporting:

Heres part of the function:

```
exportVariable<-function(VariableName){
  if(exists(VariableName)){
    #Variable exists already
    #get because VariableName is a string
    if(is.data.frame(get(VariableName))){
      VariableDF<-get(VariableName)
    } else if(is.xts(get(VariableName))) {
      VariableDF<-data.frame(date=index(get(VariableName)),coredata(get(VariableName)))
    } else {
      stop("If you want to export a variable from the workspace, you need to make sure it's a data frame or xts!") 
    }
  } else {
    stop("Variable doesn't exist")
  }

  File<-paste("O:/users/test/desktop/","Testfile.csv",sep="")

  CSVDF<-VariableDF
  CSVDF[,1]<-format(CSVDF[,1],"%Y:%m:%d")

  write.csv(CSVDF,file=File,row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
}
```

However, if someone converts his own xts to a data frame and then uses my function, it crashes later on, because I want to convert the date column (which is assumed column number 1). Heres some example showing what I mean:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
AAPLDF<-as.data.frame(AAPL)
```

You see you have here a data frame with only 1 column, the date column is the index. So how can I check within my function if it is a data frame if there's an index of dates? So I could convert it as well with:

```
VariableDF<-data.frame(date=index(get(VariableName)),coredata(get(VariableName)))
```

Comment: Why do you use get(VariableName) instead of simply VariableName ?!?

Comment: ah sorry, because I pass the VariableName as string

Comment: yes but why ? you never use the variable name, so you can remove the exists() and all get() calls.